# Unable to understand, Why parts of SVG are not drawn initially when generated from angular component?

Tags: angular, svg

I am trying to implement a stacked bar chart in angular, for achieving it, i have created two angular components, one implements axis. Another implements bar graph and uses axis component.

Following is generated SVG (copied from DOM).

```
<svg _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="460" height="400"><g _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" transform="translate(50, 10)"><g _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" _nghost-pyu-c215="" ng-reflect-scale="function scale(d) {
    var ke" ng-reflect-orient="3" transform="translate(0,370)" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="middle"><path _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" class="domain" d="M0.5,6V0.5H380.5V6"></path><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(54.28571428571432,0)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" y2="6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" y="9" dy="0.71em"> banana </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(144.7619047619048,0)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" y2="6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" y="9" dy="0.71em"> poacee </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(235.23809523809524,0)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" y2="6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" y="9" dy="0.71em"> sorgho </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(325.7142857142857,0)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" y2="6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" y="9" dy="0.71em"> triticum </text></g><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "banana,poacee,sorgho,triticum"
}--><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "function scale(d) {\n    var ke"
}--></g><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "function scale(d) {\n    var ke"
}--><g _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" _nghost-pyu-c215="" ng-reflect-scale="function scale(x) {
    return" ng-reflect-orient="4" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="end"><path _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" class="domain" d="M-6,370.5H0.5V0.5H-6"></path><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(0,370.5)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x2="-6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x="-9" dy="0.32em"> 0 </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(0,329.38888888888886)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x2="-6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x="-9" dy="0.32em"> 1 </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(0,288.27777777777777)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x2="-6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x="-9" dy="0.32em"> 2 </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(0,247.16666666666669)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x2="-6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x="-9" dy="0.32em"> 3 </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(0,206.05555555555557)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x2="-6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x="-9" dy="0.32em"> 4 </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(0,164.94444444444443)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x2="-6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x="-9" dy="0.32em"> 5 </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(0,123.83333333333334)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x2="-6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x="-9" dy="0.32em"> 6 </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(0,82.72222222222221)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x2="-6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x="-9" dy="0.32em"> 7 </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(0,41.61111111111113)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x2="-6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x="-9" dy="0.32em"> 8 </text></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" opacity="1" class="tick" transform="translate(0,0.5)"><line _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x2="-6"></line><text _ngcontent-pyu-c215="" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" x="-9" dy="0.32em"> 9 </text></g><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
}--><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "function scale(x) {\n    return"
}--></g><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "function scale(x) {\n    return"
}--><g _ngcontent-pyu-c226=""><g _ngcontent-pyu-c226=""><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-1)" x="18.09523809523813" y="328.88888888888886" height="41.11111111111114" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-1)" x="108.5714285714286" y="287.77777777777777" height="82.22222222222223" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-1)" x="199.04761904761907" y="328.88888888888886" height="41.11111111111114" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-1)" x="289.5238095238095" y="370" height="0" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "0,1,0,2,0,1,0,0"
}--></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c226=""><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-2)" x="18.09523809523813" y="287.77777777777777" height="41.111111111111086" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-2)" x="108.5714285714286" y="164.44444444444443" height="123.33333333333334" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-2)" x="199.04761904761907" y="287.77777777777777" height="41.111111111111086" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-2)" x="289.5238095238095" y="287.77777777777777" height="82.22222222222223" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "1,2,2,5,1,2,0,2"
}--></g><g _ngcontent-pyu-c226=""><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-3)" x="18.09523809523813" y="246.66666666666669" height="41.111111111111086" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-3)" x="108.5714285714286" y="0" height="164.44444444444443" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-3)" x="199.04761904761907" y="246.66666666666669" height="41.111111111111086" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><rect _ngcontent-pyu-c226="" fill="var(--avl-graph-color-3)" x="289.5238095238095" y="246.66666666666669" height="41.111111111111086" width="72.38095238095238"></rect><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "2,3,5,9,2,3,2,3"
}--></g><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "0,1,0,2,0,1,0,0,1,2,2,5,1,2,0,"
}--></g></g></svg>
```

And below is how it looks on my UI.

[image: initially rendered SVG in browser]

*Noted, both X and Y axis does not rendered.*

But most weird thing is if I use developer tools of browser to copy SVG code and remove SVG from DOM and reinsert it using Edit HTML, it renders everything correctly.

[image: After removal and reinserting SVG code]

I have tried it on FireFox, Chrome and Edge(chromium) result is same everywhere. So, I don't think it is browser issue.

Any idea, what should be going on? How i can fix it?

**Template of stacked-bar-graph component**

```
<svg [attr.width]="width + margins.right + margins.left" [attr.height]="height + margins.top + margins.bottom" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g [attr.transform]="'translate(' + margins.left+ ', ' + margins.top +')'">
    <g [attr.transform]="'translate(0,' + this.height + ')'" [sneAxis]="xAxisScale" [orient]="Orientation.bottom">
    </g>
    <g [sneAxis]="yAxisScale" [orient]="Orientation.left" ></g>
    <g>
      <g *ngFor="let stackItem of stackedData">
        <rect *ngFor="let rect of stackItem;" [attr.fill]="color(stackItem.key)"
          [attr.x]="xAxisScale(groupBy(rect.data))" [attr.y]="yAxisScale(rect[1])"
          [attr.height]="yAxisScale(rect[0]) - yAxisScale(rect[1])" [attr.width]="xAxisScale.bandwidth()"></rect>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Template of axis component (selector = 'g[sneAxis],svg[sneAxis]')**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="scale">
  <path stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" class="domain" [attr.d]="domainPathD"></path>
  <g opacity="1" [attr.transform]="transform | pureFunctionCall : (position | pureFunctionCall :value)" class="tick"
    *ngFor="let value of values">
    <line stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" [attr.x2]="x === 'x' ? k * tickSizeInner : null"
      [attr.y2]="x === 'y' ? k * tickSizeInner : null"></line>
    <text fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" [attr.x]="x === 'x' ? k * spacing : null" [attr.y]="x === 'y' ? k * spacing: null"
      [attr.dy]="dy">
      {{  format | pureFunctionCall : value }}
    </text>
  </g>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: If things are only drawn when you copy them, that usually suggests they were initially created in the wrong namespace (generally the HTML namespace rather than the SVG namespace). Copying them then autocorrects the namespace.

Comment: @RobertLongson, yes you were right. it was issue with namespace. I was able to solve it by moving everything to one component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) suggested, It was due to namespace, I was able to solve it by wrapping contents of axis component in `svg` tag.

But I think this can also be solved by renaming axis component's template file to use `.svg` extension.